# Executable will no include images used in wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, py2exe

I have created a program using python and wxpython. I have created an executable file using py2exe. IT is working fine but I had used my company logo as a splashscreen and in the printed drawings. I had to remove the splashscreen to get the executable file to work. In the error text file I get the following:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "printGland.pyc", line 418, in OnPrintPage
>     File "wx_gdi.pyc", line 3459, in DrawBitmap
>   wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "bmp.Ok()" failed at ....\src\msw\dc.cpp(1181) in wxDC::DoDrawBitmap(): invalid bitmap in wxDC::DrawBitmap

I'm assuming the bmp image has not been included in the executable file. Is there something wrong with the code when it is loaded?

```
 def __init__(self,parent,id):
    # Splash Screen
    image = wx.Image("Image.bmp",wx.BITMAP_TYPE_BMP)
    bmp = image.ConvertToBitmap()
    wx.SplashScreen(bmp,wx.SPLASH_CENTRE_ON_SCREEN|wx.SPLASH_TIMEOUT,1000,None,-1)
    wx.Yield()
```

Or is it something I should have added to the setup file when I used py2exe? Any ideas on how to remedy the situation?

Comment: which version of wxpython you're using?

Comment: From the errors it's clear that you're passing an invalid bmp file.

Comment: wxpython is 2.8. What do you mean by "invalid bmp file"?

Comment: Is the `Image.bmp` placed in the same folder of script? Or you've have to give the absolute url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [reference](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/error-with-py2exe-using-image-td2316712.html),

> Is the image file present in the current working directory? You'll
>   probably need to specify the path that the image file is located in
>   rather than just assuming the CWD as you've given.

For more discussions, [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/254930/wxpython-image-help).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make sure you include the file in the same directory as your executable. If you copy the image in with it, does it work? Otherwise, you can use wxPython's img2py script to turn your image into a Python file and bundle it in that way.

This is slightly out of date: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2008/05/23/wxpython-embedding-an-image-in-your-title-bar/

And here's the doc page: http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.tools.img2py-module.html